# ExcelPackage reading styles of excel file incorrectly

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to make some changes to my excel file

```
var fileContent = GetFileBody(); //getting byte[] of file from API
using var stream = new MemoryStream(fileContent);
{
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream)) //incorrect styles already here
    {
        //adding changes to excel file
    }
}
```

Some files load without any issue, but sometimes my whole excel sheet have broken font styles: bold = true, strike = true for all cells. I've done some different checks:

- downloaded file with API directly,
- converted fileContent to base64 and used online base64 to Excel converter,
- i tried another excel library,

file is ok. But after i create package styles are ruined (i looked under debug on properties: Cells.Style. There i can see properties `bold = true`, `strike = true`. After i save file to folder I can see those styles in my file

I tried to use `package.Load(stream)` insted of using constructor. And also searched documentation for another approach to load file (didn't found), i tried updating EPPlus to latest version, also didn't helped.

For some reason some of my files become broken. There is no much difference between non-corrupted files and corrupted ones. Only some cells of data changed.

I cannot remove incorrect styles directly. Strike style can be removed easily, but file is pretty big and there are a lot columns that have font style bold, but I don't want all of them to be bold.

And it will be very big pain to use another library. Any ideas how to avoid styles being broken?

Comment: you can reoort issues at https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/issues/ add  a sample excel file that doesn't work and see if they can fix it